# SpringBoot different connection pool to same database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have `JpaRepository<Person, UUID>` which connects to the database.
Is it possible to create a different connection pool to the same repository but from different controllers?

From controller `A` I want to have a separate connection pool than in controller `B`.

I think I should create two `DataSource` which points to same database, but I don't know how to point which controller uses which `DataSource`. Maybe I should create two `Repositories`?

Comment: What is your requirement, why can't you simply inject your repository in each controller?

Comment: I need to separate the connection pool between two controllers to avoid situation when first will lead to starvation of second.

Comment: You would need not only duplicate datasources, also entity managers, repositories etc. looks like you are trying to optimize something you shouldn't be optimizing. If something starves how could a second pool to the same database help. Just increase the size of the initial connection pool and write proper logic so that your connection don't starve. If that is the case you are keeping connections open far too long.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, you are right. I will think about not keeping connections too long instead of creating separate pools.

Comment: Did you get some issues with injecting the same repository in the 2 controllers? I suppose that if the same pool is used for both controllers, you will not have issue since a pool=multiple connexions, so your controllers will never use the same connexion at the same time. Make some tests first to validate this theory

Comment: @M.Deinum Wanted your insights on if such an approach would be useful if we wanted to prioritize certain queries to the database over the others. Say we want to segregate premium users from normal users, wherein which we can allocate more bandwidth to the premium users by setting a low connection pool size for the normal users?

Comment: If that is what you want you might want to use an `AbstractRoutingDataSource` for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you create an answer for a question with your explanation? It will be nice to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider going through the blog https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases to understand better how you can configure different connection pool and entity manager for different datasources. For your use case, we can point both to the same datasource.

Then, go about creating two different repositories for the same and through `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, point the two different transaction manager to the two different repository class paths.

Say your two different repositories are repositoryA and repositoryB, then in Controller A, inject repositoryA and in Controller B, inject repositoryB.

Answer (score 0):

To use several connection pools you have to define your own Bean for each pooled database connection by using multiple data sources.

Follow this tutorial to do so
https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7